# Multilevel menu navigation based on 'click' and not hover

Tags: jquery

i have not come across a multilevel menu that based on clicking to open the submenus because most of the existings ones are using hover effect. Could anyone point out to me where i could find a tutorial? I have all the  tags ready made but do not know how to utilize jquery to make it work as the normal multilevel menu. Thanks in advance

```
<ul id="suckertree1">

<li><a href='javascript:void(0)' target='_top'>Another child asd asd asd asd ad adas dasfe a sde fea rea</a>
    <ul class=''>
        <li><a href='http://localhost/private/product/40' target='_top'>cceeeeeooo</a></li>
        <li><a href='http://localhost/private/product/13' target='_top'>child of</a></li>
        <li><a href='javascript:void(0)' target='_top'>eawaa 5</a>
            <ul class=''>
                <li><a href='http://localhost/private/product/19' target='_top'>cccc</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href='http://localhost/private/product/14' target='_top'>errrr</a></li>
        <li><a href='http://localhost/private/product/2' target='_top'>jonni</a></li>
        <li><a href='http://localhost/private/product/29' target='_top'>Lumpur</a></li>
        <li><a href='http://localhost/private/product/41' target='_top'>makemefeel</a></li>
        <li><a href='http://localhost/private/product/16' target='_top'>sadsadsa</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Not trying to be spoilsport but I am curious why is 'hover' method not suitable for your need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know of a tutorial but [here is an example](http://jsbin.com/isezi3/).
Very quick - rather dirty but I hope it will get you on the right track.
The reason I have included `<span />`s is so you can still follow the top level link. It is also used to gives a visual cue.

Depending on your design you may want to include a bit of code to hide the drop down when you click elsewhere on the document.

Hope this helps

Comment: hi cool script but there is more than one level of this menu. minimum is 4 levels.  slidedown would not be an issue if there is one for me. I could only think of using each() but jamie shown me an alternative. tryin to integrate on that but still tryiing hard. Thanks for the effort

Comment: No worries! I've added some more levels to my example in case you are interested - might help flesh something out :) http://jsbin.com/isezi3/4

Comment: hey inrbob. i just saw your script. worked just the way i want. ill try to see if i am able to integrate to my code or not . thanks a bunch!! been stuck for 2-3 whole days for this script =)

Comment: That's no worries at all! :) If you need more help/advice with integrating this with your site just ask. It may be helpful to setup a demo with the content you have and link to it here, not necessarily though. http://jsfiddle.net/ is good if you are including and working on css. Let me know how it turns out!

Comment: hi inrbob worked marvelously~ thanks a bunch. will check the link jsfiddle.net out. it seems like a real time editor come browser stuff. thank a bunch inrbob.

Comment: sorry inrbob, wanna ask the difference between $('ul li ul').before($('<span></span>')); and $('ul li ul').before($('<span />')); It will auto open and close the span tag?

Comment: Glad its all working! There actually isnt a difference. Both of those lines create a new empty span element and insert it before the uls that are children of uls.<span /> is just shorthand for <span></span>

Comment: alright got it! one short question, if i were to make LI or A as the selector instead of <span>, how do i got about? i know i must start with this $('.suckerdiv ul li ').click(function(){})

Comment: you could try doing it this way: http://jsbin.com/isezi3/5 . I've added a class to use as an identifier for the click event since most of the 'a' tags will need the default click behaviour. You can do this in the javascript as I have or in the html if you are able

Comment: hey that was fast. did tried it but seems buggy as in the children link, the anchor is not directing to another page. I also noticed that if you are in "LINK 1 > SUB LINK 1 > SUB LINK 1.1" then i proceed to click "LINK 2" and then i proceed to "LINK 1" again, the script displayed "LINK 1 > SUB LINK 1 > SUB LINK 1.1" straight away as in they remembered my previous function. Is it possible when i click "LINK 2" all SUB <ul> is closed? Thank alot for the effort for guiding me.

Comment: sorry, haven noticed "  e.preventDefault();" changed and added javascript: void(0) to the necessary link that does not need to direct the page.

Comment: Not a very elegant solution to the sub items remaining.  http://jsbin.com/isezi3/6/ An easier option would be to apply a class to top level menu items and include those in the if statement OR better in the selectors

Comment: awesome!!! completed it with your awesome help!! haha couldnt thank you any further. been dragging this for too long. Owe you one Inrbob. Thanks! =)

Comment: your added code if ($(this).parent().parent().parent().attr('class') == 'wrapper') {
      //if you are it remoes all over classes
      $('.wrapper .over').removeClass('over');
    }
    else {
      $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('over');
    }
, does this mean, no matter how many level 4- 20 level of UL, it will close all the sublevels? because if not mistaken your parents is up to 3 ? was thinkin out of the box...

Comment: http://jsbin.com/isezi3/7 - I realised that my fix would only affect top level siblings - not sub level ones which could be an issue. So I've adjusted. As a note the previous if statement was looking to see whether an item was top level - this would only ever have been three levels from wrapper. New - more elegant - code should work regardless of level

Comment: Also if you are happy with this answer, please consider accepting it - green tick under the vote arrows :)

Comment: alright. thanks for the thorough thoughts. Ticked it already. newbie here. thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do something really simple mate, from memory you can use .toggle(); like this:

```
$('.navigation-item').click(function() {
    $('.sub-navigation-item').toggle();
});
```

I believe that should show/hide by itself. Otherwise you can literally do exactly the same as hover but replace it with a click function:

```
$('.navigation-item').click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('expanded')) {
        $(this).find('.sub-nav-container').slideUp();
        $(this).removeClass('expanded');
    }
    else {
        $(this).find('.sub-nav-container').slideDown();
        $(this).addClass('expanded');
    }
});
```

I use an if statement there to get around the fact that for hover, you can pass in 2 functions, one for hover on and one for hover off - you cannot do this with the click function, so it's a quick way to get around it :).

**EDIT:**

In the case of the code above, try something like, just to make sure it will look within itself and find the first ul, but not go any further down the hierachy? For multi-level support that is:

```
$('li a').click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('expanded')) {
        $(this).parent().find('ul:first').hide();
        $(this).removeClass('expanded');
    }
    else {
        $('#suckertree1 ul').hide();
        $(this).parent().find('ul:first').show();
        $(this).addClass('expanded');
    }        
});
```

I think jQuery UI also may have something similar to this built in - give it a google if you're still at a lose end :).

Comment: hi jamie, thanks for you swift response. I am using visibility: none. does it mean you method works for display: none?

Comment: No worries at all - slideUp and slideDown should show/hide the content automatically as do .show() and .hide().

Comment: jamie, i have edited the question and posted an example of the code. the problem if i use find, there would be alot of UL turnout to be toggled rite?

Comment: looks like visibility does not work well with show nor toggle. Edited to this  css(). your method works only for the first level. Once i am in the second level, i click, the 3rd level is visible but then the second level goes missing. any idea?

Comment: hey jamie, correct me if i am wrong, find() is to find its descendent right? in this case, your edited solution would not be able to do so as ul would not fall inside $("li a) ...

Comment: darn, i have tried so hard with using smtg like children() but seems yours works better than mine. $('.has_submenu').click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('expanded')) {
           $(this).children('ul').slideUp();
           $(this).removeClass('expanded');
       }
       else {
        
           $(this).children('ul').slideDown();
           $(this).addClass('expanded');
       }
       //$(this).children("ul").toggle();
   });

Comment: your solution works so far as to display hieracherically but when i click on another list in the same menu, it did not hide the others or clear the before clear menu.

Comment: Tell it to hide everything else first dude - $('#suckertree1 ul').hide(); - see edit. It's sounding like you want more of an accordion function now - check the jquery UI for that

Comment: hi jamie, thanks for the reply. tried out the added line for it but it seems it will hide current UL ( 2nd level and onwards ). so far your scripts works great except for this. will check out the jquery ui. Hope to find something similar to your solution as more solution is better than 1.  I wanted something like accordian function but not the effect of accordion. =)

Answer (score 0):

Although this was asked over two years ago, I thought I could help. The working code found in the comments section under the accepted answer has one flaw: The links won't function as you drill down to any level because all `<a>` tags following or in any `<li>` with a class of `expandable` are in the scope of the `e.PreventDefault()` function. Which basically means all of them.

So, there needs to be a slight fix where only link tags that are direct descendents of a `<li>` tag with the class `expandable` are affected. The fix is to add a descendent selector in the first line of the click function: `$('.nav-menu li.expandable > a').click(function (e) {`

Here's the link to the working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/disinfor/7jGj8/1/

*As an aside, I also added a bunch of classes to really show the hierarchy of what the menu is (e.g. Children, Grandchildren, Great-Grandchildren, etc.)